# I am Having issues when adding menu in admin panel magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework

I 've made a file to add my module as:  [ File as-  Axovel_MenuItem.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Axovel_MenuItem>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Axovel_MenuItem>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in folder app/etc/modules/

then i made a configuration file(config.xml) as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Axovel_MenuItem>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Axovel_MenuItem>
    </modules>
   <global>
        <helpers>
            <menuitem>
                <class>Axovel_MenuItem_Helper</class>
            </menuitem>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <menuitem>
                  <routeurfrontend>
               <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                   <module>Axovel_MenuItem</module>
                   <frontName>menuitem</frontName>
               </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
           </menuitem>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <menuitem>
                    <file>menuitem.xml</file>
                </menuitem>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <menuitem>
                            <title>Awesome Menu Item</title>
                            <children>
                                <sub_menu1>
                                    <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                                </sub_menu1>
                            </children>
                        </menuitem>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

in folder app/code/local/Axovel/MenuItem/etc/

then i made a Adminhtml Configuration File(adminhtml.xml) as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <menu>
       <menuitem>
           <title>Awesome Menu Item</title>
               <sort_order>20</sort_order>
               <children>
               <sub_menu1>
                    <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <!--  <action>menuitem/index/index</action>       -->
               </sub_menu1>
            </children>
       </menuitem>
   </menu>
</config>
```

in folder app/code/local/Axovel/MenuItem/etc/

and made a Helper File(Data.php) as:

```
<?php
class Axovel_MenuItem_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
?>
```

in folder app/code/local/Axovel/MenuItem/Helper/

I also made a Controller file(IndexController.php) as:

```
    <?php
    class Axovel_MenuItem_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
       public function indexAction()
        {

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();

         }
   }
?>
```

But Not Getting the Desired Results, I am not able to see my custom menu Item

Even i am not able to call my indexController/indexAction directly with Hyperlink as

http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/menuitem/index/index

there is something Wrong in config.xml but i am not able to figure it out, can anyone please Help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it is probably a caching issue. If you are new to magento, the cache can be easy to forget and really cause some problems for you. You should try clearing that in the backend or from the command line. cache is found in the var folder and you will want to empty bother the cache folder and the full_page_cache folder.

I don't know if the menu button will work or not because you didn't give any code that would generate a new page or block.